# In Laravel how to add language part in all anchor links?

Tags: laravel

I am using blade template and put simple url like

```
<a href="aboutus">About us</a>
```

Now I change language like

mydomain.com/hn/

then how i can add language part in all url like

mydomain.com/hn/aboutus

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Laravel localization. It may be useful to you.
[Laravel Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a link like this

```
<a href="/aboutus/hn">About us</a>
```

and then in routes/web.php make a route for it like this

```
Route::get('aboutus/hn', function () {
    return 'About us page';
});
```